# how to add the camera capture images in array in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Want to add the camera capture images added in array and load that array in collection view  display the all the images

```
///here i get the capture image in picker

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
      UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
      imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
       imagePicker.delegate = self;
       imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
       [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
 }


- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

     // in this part how can add the camera capture image in array  
     // and load that array value in collection view..
}
```

help me how to achieve this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested what I am about to write, but you could try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

   //declare before NSMutableArray *_mutableArray;
   _mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

...

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
   //dismiss UIImagePickerController
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

   //take image from info
   UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

   //store image into NSMutableArray
   [_mutableArray addObject:image];

   //reload collectionView
   [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

and in `collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //this is a custom CollectionViewCell
   CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.imageA.image = [_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   return cell;

}
```

Comment: Exactly correct code... i make mistake in    cell.imageA.image = [_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; in part thank you so much...

Comment: @srini imageA is my custom image in custom cell.. anyway happy to have helped! :)